# Key press in a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, command-line, process

```
try:
    subprocess.run(exe_path)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    print('Successful Extracted')
except Exception as exe:
    print(exe.args)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
```

The point is to run the EXE of windows but it needs an input of keyboard to end its process, and it will remain stuck over there unless a keyboard input is given physically. Right now I am facing an issue as

> `subprocess.run('some_exe')`

is running the process and after successfully run asking

> `Press Any Key To Exit`

while I have already mentioned next to **subprocess.run**

> `keyboard.press_and_release('enter')`

and it's coming to the next line unless we press the button from the keyboard manually

**NOTE: python3.8**

Comment: `subprocess.run()` does not finish until the called program exits.  Your `keyboard` call therefore cannot possibly happen at any time where it will do you any good.  You either need to use `subprocess.Popen()` (which doesn't wait for program exit), or do the 'enter' key press from a different thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of a reproducible example, say we want to run the following Python script as a subprocess, let's call it `script.py`.

```py
input('Press Enter to exit.')
```

It won't terminate until the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If we want to emulate the key press, we can just send a newline character to the subprocess's `stdin` using [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Like so:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['python', 'script.py'], stdin=PIPE, text=True)
process.communicate('\n')
```

The external program doesn't have to be a Python script, it can be any executable. Just replace `['python', 'script.py']` with the corresponding command-line call, e.g. `['some_exe']`.

Obviously this also works if the external program accepts *any* key to exit. Only sending special keys which don't have an obvious text representation, such as <kbd>F1</kbd>, would complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .vbs file to run your .exe file or python script without console debugging window:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c  python main.py"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

If you have .exe file just replace `python main.py` with `yourFile.exe`.